# Specific examples of tonal Chinese words rendered into Japanese

Tags: kanji, homophonic-kanji, chinese, pitch-accent, homonyms

It is often said that Japanese contains a large number of homonyms because there was no way to render tonal Chinese words into Japanese. This makes complete sense. But I am looking for specific examples of Sino-Japanese words which are homonyms but where their original Chinese counterparts are not homonyms, i.e. the Chinese words have tonal differences, but the Japanese words do not.

Comment: Have you tried looking up Japanese homophones in a Chinese dictionary such as YellowBridge? https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php

Comment: @mamster I'm not sure how you would do that. For example, if I want to search for the Japanese word きゅうよう (which is a homonym), how can I search for that in the dictionary you linked?

Comment: For future reference, you’d do this by searching for the words in kanji, which are usually the same as traditional hanzi.

Comment: @mamster The *tones* that are relevant to the question are the [four tones in Middle Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_tones_\(Middle_Chinese\)). The Mandarin tones, while having a correspondence to Middle Chinese tones, aren't a 1-to-1 relation, and most dictionaries (including yellowbridge) won't give Middle Chinese reconstructions.

Answer (score 6):

<sub>Keywords: MC, Middle Chinese; OC, Old Chinese: MJ: Middle Japanese; OJ,
 Old Japanese; 呉, *Go'on*; 漢, *Kan'on*; 唐, *Tō-on*; /<sup>(absence of superscript)</sup>/ or 平, level tone; /<sup>X</sup>/ or 上, rising tone; /<sup>H</sup>/ or 去, departing tone; /p̚/, /t̚/, /k̚/, or 入, entering or checked tone*</sub>

*On'yomi* homophones are numerous, but the loss of syllable distinction comes from multiple sources, of which loss of tones upon importation into Old - Middle Japanese from Early / Late MC is just one. There are at least two other major sources:

- Phonological shifts in the Japanese language itself. If you've dabbled in [historical kana orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_kana_orthography#Complete_tables_of_differences), you may recognise patterns when going from historical spellings to modern spellings. In fact, the historical kana spellings for many *on'yomi* represented a more accurate mora-sequence approximation of MC syllables than modern Japanese spelling, but these written distinctions were later lost in spoken Japanese. E.g.:

  - **「協」**(呉音: *originally* **[けふ]{kefu}**, *MC* **/ɦep̚/**),**「京」**(呉音: *originally* **[きやう]{kyau}**, *MC* **/kˠiæŋ/**), now both reduced to **きょう**
  - **「帳」**(漢音: *originally* **[ちやう]{tyau}**, *MC* **/ʈɨɐŋ<sup>H</sup>/**),**「兆」**(漢音: *originally* **[てう]{teu}**, *MC* **/ɖˠiᴇu<sup>X</sup>/**), now both reduced to **ちょう**
- The waves of importation of vocabulary, with readings now classified as [呉音](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go-on), [漢音](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kan-on), and [唐音](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C5%8D-on). All of these are snapshots of both different eras of Middle Chinese phonology and different Chinese topolects during those eras. Combined with the above phonological shifts in Japanese, you can get even syllables which sounded vastly different in different topolects of Chinese in different eras (not even considering tone) converging in Japanese. E.g.

  - **「清」**(唐音: **しん**, *MC* **/t͡sʰiᴇŋ/**), **「森」**(呉音: *originally* **[しむ]{simu}**, *MC* **/ʃˠiɪm/**), now both reduced to **しん**
  - **「生」**(呉音: *originally* **[しやう]{syau}**, *MC* **/ʃˠæŋ/** ),**「匠」**(漢音: *originally* **[しやう]{syau}**, *MC* **/d͡zɨɐŋ<sup>H</sup>/**), now both reduced to **しょう**; for reference, the 漢音 of「生」and 呉音 of「匠」are **せい** and originally **[ざう]{zau}**, respectively.

The applicable class of words to answer this question are then those which had syllables distinguished in MC by tone only and have merged in OJ purely due to this loss of tone information upon importation. E.g.

- 京 (/kˠiæŋ/, 平) vs. 敬 (/kˠiæŋ<sup>H</sup>/, 去) both became [きやう]{kyau} -> きょう;
- 真 (/t͡ɕiɪn/, 平) vs. 震 (/t͡ɕiɪn<sup>H</sup>/, 去) both became しん
- 朝 (/ɖˠiᴇu/, 平) vs. 兆 (/ɖˠiᴇu<sup>X</sup>/, 上) both became [てう]{teu} -> ちょう;
- 理 (/lɨ<sup>X</sup>/, 上) vs. 吏 (/lɨ<sup>H</sup>/, 去) both became り
- 相 (/sɨɐŋ<sup>H</sup>/, 去) vs. 想 (/sɨɐŋ<sup>X</sup>/, 上) both became [さう]{sau} -> そう

---

*Entering/Checked tone [is not really a tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checked_tone).

Comment: Wow, this is very surprising. It was my understanding that the failure to discern tones was directly responsible for the existence of many Japanese homophones. For example, Richmond (2005) claims that "morphemes which could be distinguished in spoken Chinese from their differences in tonal qualities, were all assimilated as one indistinguishable morpheme in Japanese". He gives the examples 馬, 麻, and 間 as being phonologically distinct in Chinese but homophonous in Japanese. But your point would be that in Early Middle Chinese that wouldnt have been the case, right?

Comment: @kandyman sorry, I made a huge mistake when copying the MC reconstructions and misinterpreted them. Please see revised answer. BTW, 馬, 麻, and 間 is a very strange set of examples to demonstrate homophony; only 馬 and 麻 are pronounced with the same syllable in Chinese, with [間]{ま} being a *kun'yomi* and so is irrelevant; also the common *Jōyo* pronunciations of 馬 and 麻 are ば and ま, respectively, and so aren't homophones.

Comment: @ droooze Thank you again for your thorough answer. I'd like to use those examples in a presentation. Do you know of a good academic source or paper from which I can provide some supporting citations?

Comment: @ droooze Another comment I have is this: if the number of homophones caused by tonal difference is as small as you say, then the majority of the homophones must be produced by waves of importing and phonological shifts, as you mentioned. But are those factors really enough to explain the large number of homophones in Japanese? It seems a bit of a stretch to me, but I'm certainly no expert in Old Japanese/Middle Chinese.

Comment: @kandyman The *first cause* of the majority of the homophones seems to have occurred when OJ tried to capture complex MC syllables (tone is but just one aspect of this). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Japanese_vocabulary#Chart_of_correspondences for the kinds of loss of phonological information that occurred. There were only 3 distinct phonemic tones in MC, but over half of that chart details 4-6 consonants that were collapsed into 1-2 consonants. This collapse occurs on average slightly less than twice in a syllable (occurring almost always both in the onset and final).

Comment: @kandyman this was a moderately-far upstream cause, that you wouldn't see the major effect of until Japanese phonology shifts came into play. It's a kind of compound effect, if that makes sense. Anyway, this phonological information is freely available online, so I can't provide a reference. Any qualitative opinions comes from my own reading over the years, so take it with a grain of salt. Any corrections by a more knowledgeable reader are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

The most homophones that I know of are the various words pronounced きかん (ordered by frequency in Japanese)

1. 機関 *jīguān* 機關・机关 engine/institution
2. 期間 *qī​jiān* 期间 time interval/period
3. 器官 *qì​guān* organ
4. 基幹 *jīgàn* mainstay/nucleus
5. 帰還 *guīhuán* 歸還・归还 repatriation/return
6. 気管 ​*qìguǎn* 氣管・气管 trachea
7. 旗艦 *qí​jiàn* 旗舰 flagship
8. 季刊 *jì​kān* quarterly (e.g. magazine)
9. 奇観 ​*qíguān* 奇觀・奇观 wonderful sight

<sub>Formatting:　*kanji*　Mandarin *pīnyīn*　[traditional Chinese・]simplified Chinese　English.</sub>

In (Modern) Chinese all are pronounced differently.

In (Modern) Japanese, they can be only partly differentiated using pitch accent. The pitch accent given in 新明解 日本語アクセント辞典 groups them as follows:

- きかん【LHH】 ⁴基幹、⁵帰還、⁶気管、⁸季刊、⁹奇観
- きかん【LHH】、きかん【LHL】 ⁷旗艦
- きかん【LHL】、きかん【LHH】 ((新は きかん【HLL】)) ¹機関、²期間、³器官

Note that 94% of the occurrences of きかん (numbers from the written language) are 機関 and 器官. For disambiguation, context is always king.

Comment: Great work, thanks very much. Can I ask for your source on the Chinese translations?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but how did you format the words to include red pitch accents with lines, small superscript, etc?

Comment: The "translations" (more loose associations) are given without warranty — the English words are somewhere between the Chinese (I used https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary and https://dict.leo.org/chinesisch-deutsch/) and the Japanese (https://jisho.org/). The translations are not really related to the question anyway, but I thought it would be better to have imprecise translations than no translations at all.

Comment: For general formatting, see [How should I format my questions on Japanese Language SE?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/807/1628) — for pitch accent it's part of the furigana engine, giving the "reading" as, say, LHLLHL. The superscript numbers are part of Unicode (and are part of my keyboard layout), but you can achieve the same using the HTML tags `<sup>...</sup>`. Finally, you can always peek at the code of an answer by clicking `edit` under the question.

Comment: I don't think that it's appropriate to use Modern Mandarin pronunciations to answer the question. Some of these were still distinguished in Middle Japanese and them becoming homophones in Modern Japanese is to do with sound shifts from Middle Japanese to Modern Japanese, not to do with the loss of tones in these words upon importation from Chinese.

Comment: Wow, does 大辞林 really give ② for 期間? I've ever been thinking it's ①. Anyway, ⓪ should be LHH instead of LLL.

Comment: @droooze You're right, the question says "**original** Chinese counterparts" which can only mean Chinese words at the time of being adopted into Japanese; this should mean Middle Chinese & Middle Japanese. I guess I answered a different question — "examples of homophones in Japanese whose Chinese counterparts are not homophones". Please do post an answer. I do not know any Middle Chinese / Middle Japanese.

Comment: @broccoliforest 大辞林 gives ②① for 期間. I updated the answer with pitch accents from a pitch accent dictionary — this would have been the more natural choice for a reference =)

Comment: @droooze You are correct, I was trying to find examples of the original Chinese pronunciations which were distinct but which were transliterated as one sound in Japanese.